# A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, ping, icmp

Short version: *Why does `Test-Connection` report "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup" for an offline host on a different subnet?*

---

I'm using PowerShell to ping a remote host with the `Test-Connection` cmdlet:

```
$Computer = "COMPUTER01"
Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 3
```

I receive the following error message:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: Testing connection to computer
'COMPUTER01' failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database
lookup ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A non-recoverable error
occurred during a database lookup.
```

My DNS servers are all Windows AD Controllers running the DNS service. I am able to resolve the hostname to IP address using `nslookup`:

```
Name:    computer01.domain.com
Address:  192.168.2.153
```

The MS website says the following:

> **This is a nonrecoverable error.** This indicates that some sort of
>   nonrecoverable error occurred during a database lookup. This may be
>   because the database files (for example, BSD-compatible HOSTS,
>   SERVICES, or PROTOCOLS files) could not be found, or a DNS request was
>   returned by the server with a severe error.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

***Question: What "database lookup" might be failing?***

---

### Troubleshooting pt. 1

I have tried to `ping` the same host, which also fails but with a more familiar message:

```
C:\> ping COMPUTER01

Pinging COMPUTER01.domain.com [192.168.2.153] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.220: Destination host unreachable.
```

Running `tracert` for the target IP address confirms this:

```
C:\> tracert -d 192.168.2.153

7    40 ms    40 ms    40 ms  192.168.0.220
8  192.168.0.220  reports: Destination host unreachable.
```

> This message indicates one of two problems: either the local system
>   has no route to the desired destination, or a remote router reports
>   that it has no route to the destination...
>
> If the message is "Reply From < IP address >: Destination Host Unreachable,"
>   then the routing problem occurred at a remote router, whose address is
>   indicated by the "< IP address >" field. Use the appropriate utility
>   or facility to check the IP routing table of the router assigned the
>   IP address of < IP address >.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940095.aspx

---

### Troubleshooting pt. 2

I had a look at the ICMP packets using WireShark. I can see that the response from this router is:

```
Type: 3 (Destination unreachable)
Code: 1 (Host unreachable)
```

> *Destination unreachable* is generated by the host or its inbound
>   gateway to inform the client that the destination is unreachable
>   for some reason... Unreachable TCP ports notably respond with TCP
>   RST rather than a Destination Unreachable type 3 as might be expected.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable

### And finally

I also have separate/independent confirmation that the target host is known to be off the network, which explains why the router cannot "reach" the target. I am still wondering why the `Test-Connection` cmdlet threw what is (to me) such a misleading exception message.

Comment: I will have a look at the hosts file (unlikely to be the problem I think) and wonder about the cache. Thankfully (?) the problem is still happening so I can test some things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the troubleshooting I have put in to this, my conclusion is simply that `Test-Connection` is returning a very unhelpful error message and/or misinterpreting the "Destination host unreachable" response being received from the router.

If anyone else is seeing this I would suggest running a `tracert` to confirm whether there is any device in the route which may be returning a response to the ping request.

If you have any way other than ping to determine if the host is online or not that will make a good sanity check and help you work out whether you can ignore these errors (using `-ErrorAction`) on the assumption that the host is offline:

```
$Computer = "COMPUTER01"

if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
  "Online"
} else {
  "Offline"
}
```

---

As a side note, it seemed that the only difference between `ping` and `Test-Connection` was that the time-to-live (TTL) on the ICMP packet differed between `ping` (128) and `Test-Connection` (80). The latter cmdlet does include a `-TimeToLive` switch if that is important to anyone; it didn't make any difference in my testing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing. You made me look at the docs as I was having the same error.

It appears that this is a "feature" of `Test-Connection`; they appear to know about this as they provide a workaround.

The help for `Test-Connection` says if you want it to return only a boolean you should use the `-Quiet` switch when calling otherwise it tries to return an object. Here it is verbatim:

> When you use the AsJob parameter, the cmdlet returns a job object.
>   When you use the Quiet parameter, it returns a Boolean. Otherwise,
>   this cmdlet returns a Win32_PingStatus object for each ping.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx

So `-Quiet` it is for me rather than `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Comment: Thanks. Useful work-around for this problem especially when I only need true|false for whether the host is ping-able.